# Erro 'BotFalante' object is not callable

Tags: python, chatbot

Estou criando um 'assistente virtual' em Python, mas to com algumas dificuldades. Segue o código:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer  
from chatterbot import ChatBot  
import pyttsx3  
import speech_recognition as sr

en = pyttsx3.init()  
en.setProperty('voice',b'brazil')  
rec = sr.Recognizer()  


class BotFalante(ChatBot):  
    def escuta(self,frase=None):  
          try:  
            with sr.Microphone() as mic:  
                fala = rec.listen(mic)  
            frase = rec.recognize_google(fala,language='pt')  
            frase = frase.replace('aprendi','aprende')  
            print(frase)  
        except sr.UnknownValueError:  
            print('Deu erro na identificação')  
            return ('')  
        return super().escuta(frase=frase)  

    def fala(self,frase):  
        en.say(frase)  
        en.runAndWait()  
        super().fala(frase)  

Bot = BotFalante('Zuleide')  
while True:  
    frase = Bot.escuta()  
    resp = Bot.pensa(frase)  
    Bot.fala(resp)  
    if resp == ('falou'):  

        break
```

O erro que da é:

```
line 33, in <module>
resp = Bot.pensa(frase)
AttributeError: 'BotFalante' object has no attribute 'pensa'
```

Comment: E em que momento do código há `resp = Bot(frase)`? No que você postou não tem.

Comment: No while,  o correto é: frase = Bot.escuta()
    resp = Bot(frase)  
    Bot.fala(resp)  
    if resp == ('falou'):

Comment: A classe `ChatBot` define o método `__call__` para ser chamável desta forma?

Comment: eu comiti um equívoco, acabei de corrigir o código, perdão

Comment: Então a pergunta passa a ser: a classe `BotFalante` deveria possuir o método `pensa`? Você não definiu ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resp = Bot.pensa(frase)
AttributeError: 'BotFalante' object has no attribute 'pensa'
```

O objeto `Bot` é uma instância da classe `BotFalante`. Se você está tentando acessar um método `.pensa(...)` nesse objeto, esse método `pensa` precisa estar definido em algum destes lugares: Ou na própria classe `BotFalante`, da mesma forma que você definiu os outros métodos `escuta` e `fala`, ou herdado de uma das "classes-pai" dela, como por exmeplo da classe `ChatBot`.

No caso esse método não foi definido, e é por isso que você está recebendo o erro.